# Start Reading data from nth and mthc oluumns using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a excel sheet where data starts from nth and mth row.

[The data is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SjoV.png)

I have many excel sheets like this where the starting point of data is different.

How can we find row and col numbers in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data with [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). Then you can try to check that if all values in the columns are `NaN`, then drop them. Similar for the rows.

Alternatively, you can try to use [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to read in the sheet until you reach the first cell that is non-negative, save the coordinate where it is non-`NaN` and feed this into `pandas.read_excel`. Here you can consider multiple different strategies, scan rows (up to a certain width), scan columns (up to a certain length), or even diagonal (i.e. A1, B1, A2, A3, B2, C1, etc...) to find an edge/corner and do some magic to then go up/left to find the real corner and feed this back in to `pandas.read_excel`.

It all depends on how different the starting points of the data are.